# Java - log4 prints to neither console nor file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to use log4j to print messages from a standalone Java app to the console in Eclipse, but it's not printing anything. Here's the code:

Declaration:

```
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnalyticsBackupUtil.class);
```

Print statements:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String log4jConfigFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfigFile);
    logger.debug("this is a debug log message");
    logger.info("this is a information log message");
    logger.warn("this is a warning log message");
    logger.error("this is an error log message");
```

...

properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender1,Appender2
log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=applog.txt
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j 1.x does not have a method `LoggerFactory.getLogger`. You are probably using `org.slf4j.Logger` and `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

If this is intentional (using a logging API like SLF4j allows to easily change the backend), you need to add the [`slf4j-log4j12`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12) binding to the classpath.